# Argument type auto deduction and anonymous lambda functions

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

Lets say I have these lines of code;

```
std::vector<int> ints;
std::for_each(ints.begin(), ints.end(), [](int& val){ val = 7; });
```

However, I dont want to specify the argument type in my lambda functions, ie, I want to write something like this;

```
std::for_each(ints.begin(), ints.end(), [](auto& val){ val = 7; });
```

Is there anyway this can be achieved?

*(boost::lambda doesn't need types to be specified...)*

---

***Update:***

For now I use a macro: `#define _A(container) decltype(*std::begin(container))` so I can do:

```
std::for_each(ints.begin(), ints.end(), [](_A(ints)& val){ val = 7; });
```

Comment: At least for this, why not just `std::fill(ints.begin(), ints.end(), 7);`?

Comment: Yes, in this case std::fill could be used, however, thats not my question.

Comment: That's why I entered it as a comment, not an answer...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No. "Polymorphic lambdas" is what this feature was referred to during the C++ committee discussions, and it was not standardized. The parameter types of a lambda must be specified.

You can use `decltype` though:

```
std::for_each(ints.begin(), ints.end(), [](decltype(*ints.begin())& val){ val = 7; });
```

Comment: Damn it, I've developed quite a good flow using auto as often as possible.

Comment: typedef decltype(*beg(ints)) type; if you think the decltype syntax is laborious.

Comment: Polymorphic/generic lambdas ar part of C++14 though: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Generic_lambdas

Answer (score 15):

Your preferred syntax is legal as of C++14, and is referred to as a generic lambda or polymorphic lambda.

http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/04/n3649-generic-polymorphic-lambda-expressions-r3

```
auto lambda = [](auto x) { return x; };
lambda(5);
lambda("hello");
lambda(std::vector<int>({5, 4, 3}));
```

As of C++20, we can also use this syntax for regular functions:

```
auto f(auto x) { return x; }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a container you may try something like this

```
template<typename Container>
void reset(Container c)
{
   for_each(c.begin(),c.end(),[](typename Container::reference val) { val=7; });
}
```

Comment: If your function is not a template function but works on a concrete type (as is my case), you can simply do: `std::for_each(ints.begin(), ints.end(), [](ints::reference val) { ... });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <typename ValTy>
std::function<void(ValTy&)> polymorphicLambda ()
{
    return std::function<void(ValTy&)> ([](ValTy& val) -> void { val = 7; } );
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> ints(5);

    std::generate_n(ints.begin(), 5, []() { return 0; });
    std::for_each(ints.begin(), ints.end(), [](int& val) { std::cout << val << "\t"; });
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::for_each(ints.begin(), ints.end(), polymorphicLambda<int>());
    std::for_each(ints.begin(), ints.end(), [](int& val) { std::cout << val << "\t"; });
    std::cout << std::endl;


    std::vector<double> doubles(5);

    std::generate_n(doubles.begin(), 5, []() { return 0; });
    std::for_each(doubles.begin(), doubles.end(), [](double& val) { std::cout << val << "\t"; });
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::for_each(doubles.begin(), doubles.end(), polymorphicLambda<double>());
    std::for_each(doubles.begin(), doubles.end(), [](double& val) { std::cout.precision(2); std::cout << std::fixed << val << "\t"; });
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You might also be able to do some funky stuff with lambdas that don't return void and also with variadic templates to pass in multiple params to the lambda.

Comment: I dont get it? what is the win?

Comment: The win is not having to redeclare your lambda for each argument type. It does not address your question though

Comment: Also not clear to me is why you would use this instead of a standard template function declaration