# Possible to simplify this expression?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

Lets say I have a class with a member variable:

```
std::unordered_map<KeyType, std::shared_ptr<ValueType>> myMap
```

and in a member function I want to do the following:

```
std::for_each(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), [](std::pair<const KeyType, std::shared_ptr<ValueType>>& pair){pair.second->someMethod(); });
```

Is there anyway to shorten the lambda expression?  I thought I could do this but it was not valid syntax:

```
std::for_each(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), [](decltype(myMap::valueType)& pair){pair.second->someMethod(); });
```

Comment: `using namespace std;` would shorten it a bit.

Comment: @Soohjun good god, don't do that :(

Comment: @111111: It’s fine in a small local scope in a definition, just not globally or in a header.

Comment: @JonPurdy I know it can be used in some cases but it is A LOT easier to just not use it. I would far rather see `using std::unodered_map` or whatever than including the entire namespace. And I really don't think recommending at as a comment in this question is at all constructive.

Comment: @111111: I disagree. It’s more constructive to say “do it when it’s appropriate” than “don’t do it”. Whether it’s more *helpful* is another jar of jam.

Comment: @JonPurdy I really don't think, things are in namespace for a reason, and that isn't to have the namespace effectively merged with the current NS. The fact is it is never wrong to prefix a namespace, however it is Often (but not always) wrong to include an namespace, so it is a much better catch all advice to just recommend that you prefix. Especially by the medium of Stackoverflow comments where your hardly going to be able to teach some when and when not to prefix.

Comment: @111111: Fair enough. It’s fine to err on the side of caution.

Comment: You're trying to `decltype` a type rather than a expression -- you already have a type (though it's misspelled). ;-]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recomend `typedef`ing complex templates like the assoc containers, for this reason so you could do something like:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<KeyType, std::shared_ptr<ValueType>> map_type;

map_type myMap;

//do with map

std::for_each(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), 
    [](typename map_type::value_type& pair){
        pair.second->someMethod(); 
});
```

or without the typedef

```
std::for_each(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), 
    [](typename decltype(myMap)::value_type& pair){
        pair.second->someMethod(); 
});
```

decltype gets the type of an object, you need to use the typename defined in a templated class, to do this you use the `typename` keyword. This is necessary in case a template specialisation doesn't have that typedef.

Answer (score 9):

I wouldn’t bother with a lambda at all. Unlike the other standard algorithms, `for_each()` is not any more expressive or readable than the equivalent `for`.

```
for (auto& p : myMap)
    p.second->someMethod();

for (auto p = myMap.begin(); p != myMap.end(); ++p)
    p->second->someMethod();
```

Comment: Actually, I would even say that `for_each` is as well as deprecated with the new range-for syntax. You had some benefits before (at the cost of writing a predicate), but now ? It's no even worth it.

Comment: @Klaim: Good point. Then again, there is always an ordinary `for`. If it weren’t for the typing issues, `for_each()` might save some keystrokes, but as it is, `for` still comes out on top in many cases.

Comment: Interesting, this all came about after I read this article today: http://evincarofautumn.blogspot.com/2012/04/c-functional-style-tips.html  but perhaps in this case using a simple ranged for loop is the best answer?

Comment: @JonPurdy Actually, I was commenting MatthieuM. remark that I find wrong as there are interesting differences between range-based-for and for_each that make them both useful, including the classic for as you wrote it. They are not eclipsing each other.

Comment: @grivescorbett: I wrote that article. `for` is sometimes better. :P

Answer (score 0):

I've made a macro which goes as this:
// Anonymous lambda type deduction from container name

```
#define _A(container)\
  std::remove_reference<decltype(*std::begin(container))>::type
```

In your case use as:

```
std::for_each(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), [](_A(myMap)& pair) {
  pair.second->someMethod(); 
});
```

*Note:*
The `remove_reference` is needed to preserve constness if typing `[](const _A(myMap)& pair)`, otherwise the `&` removes the `const` declaration.

Comment: No it's not, and you can use it for every algorithm, not just for_each.

Comment: I don't mean the macro itself (though, well, I use `typedef` usually so it would not be as useful with my coding style), I mean the `for_each` you wrote. `for (auto& p: myMap) { p.second->someMethod(); }` is **much** shorter.

Comment: Yes, in the case of foreach, but I took it a bit like a general question regarding all algorithms (and the code gets alot more readible if you use different algorithms instead of for\forloops for everything). And nowadays, with auto, you don't need to typedef everything.

Comment: I still like to `typedef` because `std::map<int, std::string>` has no semantics, but `IdNameMap` has. It's not just about making things shorter :) Furthermore, function parameters still need to be typed, and I'm moving more and more toward short functions.

Comment: To be be honest, I typedef every here and there too. But, this information (IdNameMap) can be but into the variable name. Also, it annoys me that my answer didn't get accepted as the correct one, as I think it's the best answer to this question :)

Comment: Tastes vary :) I find your macro relatively elegant (not its name, which is a reserved identifier). My main peeve is that, really, `auto` should be supported here. After all, for predicates we can use template methods, so it's not like the compiler does not know how to deal with this...

Comment: I agree totally; I even had a question about this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712826/argument-type-auto-deduction-and-anonymous-lambda-functions

Comment: Imho, I think the reason we dont have this is because the standard commitee doesn't work with C++ on a daily basis, and therefor tend to focus on things like variadic templates (which, according to me, should have a lot lower priority).

Comment: I would disagree wrt variadic templates :) As for lambdas, I believe it is a simple omission. I am afraid it would not make it into a DR though.