# std::max with lambda and auto

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, auto

Shouldn't this be possible with C++11?
With the current clang compilers (Xcode 5 on OS X 10.8) it fails to compile:

```
std::max_element(group->GetComponents().begin(), group->GetComponents().end(),
                 [](auto a, auto b) { return a.length > b.length; });
```

The error message is:
*Stuff.cp:68:40: 'auto' not allowed in function prototype*

Comment: Function argument types cannot be `auto`. There is no way to deduce the type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Argument type auto deduction and anonymous lambda functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712826/argument-type-auto-deduction-and-anonymous-lambda-functions)

Comment: Also: [How does generic lambda work in C++14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233547/how-does-generic-lambda-work-in-c14)

Comment: `Shouldn't this be possible with C++11`? That's what [C++11 and the Lack of Polymorphic Lambdas - Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643039/c11-and-the-lack-of-polymorphic-lambdas-why) addresses.

Comment: @RSahu In this specific context (template algorithm) it could be deduced from the type of the collection, right?

Comment: @ATV the link from DarkWanderer's comment provides a nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In C++1y you have generic lambdas, so the syntax will compile in [clang 3.5](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cff9434d0c61d93f). The lambda will look like this:

```
class /* unnamed */
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    T operator () (T a) const { return a; }
};
```